# CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_video_search

Tags: plsql

Create a procedure called proc_video_search to search for a video and display the name, copy ID, format, and status of the video’s copies. In addition, the checkout dates and due dates are also displayed for unreturned copies. The damaged copies (Status = 'D') are excluded in your output. Sort your output by the video name (Name) and then the copy ID (CopyID).

```
    $ CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_video_search  (
         p_VideoName        VARCHAR2, 
         p_FormatName       VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)    as
      v_Count             NUMBER;
      v_TotalCopies   NUMBER; v_Avalb  NUMBER;v_FormatName  VARCHAR2(100);
      v_VideoName   VARCHAR2(100); v_CopyID  VARCHAR2(100);v_DueDate DATE;
      v_Status    VARCHAR2(100); v_CheckoutDate DATE;
     CURSOR asdf IS 
       SELECT T_VIDEO.Name, T_COPY.CopyID, Status,T_VIDEO_FORMAT.NAME
       FROM T_VIDEO
       INNER JOIN T_COPY  ON T_VIDEO.VideoID = T_COPY.VideoID
       INNER JOIN T_VIDEO_FORMAT  ON T_VIDEO_FORMAT.FormatID = 
            T_VIDEO.FormatID
       WHERE Status !='D' AND UPPER(T_VIDEO.Name) like '%' || 
                    UPPER(p_VideoName) ||  '%'
       OR UPPER(T_VIDEO_FORMAT.NAME)= UPPER(p_FormatName) 
       ORDER BY T_VIDEO.Name,  T_COPY.CopyID;

    BEGIN
       SELECT       COUNT(*)
       INTO     v_Count
       FROM     T_VIDEO  
        WHERE UPPER(T_VIDEO.Name) like '%' || UPPER(p_VideoName) ||  '%'  ;

      IF v_count = 0 THEN     
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('****  '||v_Count|| ' results found for ' || 
           p_VideoName||'.  *****');   
        RETURN;
      END IF;

        SELECT   count(T_COPY.CopyID) INTO   v_TotalCopies
        FROM T_COPY INNER JOIN T_VIDEO ON T_COPY.VideoID = T_VIDEO.VideoID
        INNER JOIN T_VIDEO_FORMA ON T_VIDEO_FORMAT.FormatID =
                              T_VIDEO.FormatID
        WHERE Status !='D' AND UPPER(T_VIDEO.Name) like '%' || 
             UPPER(p_VideoName) ||'%'
                 OR UPPER(T_VIDEO_FORMAT.NAME)=UPPER(p_FormatName);

        SELECT   count(T_COPY.CopyID)INTO   v_Avalb FROM T_COPY
        INNER JOIN T_VIDEO  ON T_COPY.VideoID = T_VIDEO.VideoID
        INNER JOIN T_VIDEO_FORMAT ON T_VIDEO_FORMAT.FormatID = 
                      T_VIDEO.FormatID
         WHERE Status ='A' AND UPPER(T_VIDEO.Name) like '%' || 
                    UPPER(p_VideoName) ||'%'
          OR UPPER(T_VIDEO_FORMAT.NAME)=UPPER(p_FormatName);    

         IF v_TotalCopies >=0 THEN
            IF  p_FormatName IS NULL THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_TotalCopies||' results found for '|| 
           p_VideoName||' . (Available copies:'|| v_Avalb|| ')' );
        ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_TotalCopies||' results found for '|| 
              p_VideoName||'('|| p_FormatName||') . (Available copies:'|| 
                     v_Avalb|| ')' );
        end if;

        OPEN asdf;
          LOOP
               FETCH asdf INTO   v_VideoName, v_CopyID, v_Status, 
                  v_FormatName ;  exit when asdf%NOTFOUND ;

              SELECT COUNT(CheckoutDate)  
              INTO v_Count FROM  T_RENTAL WHERE CopyID = v_CopyID;

             IF v_Count = 1 THEN
               SELECT  CheckoutDate,DueDate
               INTO v_CheckoutDate,v_DueDate
               FROM  T_RENTAL
               WHERE CopyID = v_CopyID; 
             end if;

             DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD('-', 53, '-'));
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD('Name:',30) || RPAD(v_VideoName,15));
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD('CopyID:',30) ||   RPAD(v_CopyID,15));
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD('Format:',30) ||   
               RPAD(v_FormatName,15));
              IF v_Status = 'A' THEN v_Status := 'Available';END IF;
              IF v_Status = 'R' THEN v_Status := 'Rented'; END IF;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD('Status:',30) ||   RPAD(v_Status,15));  
              IF v_Status ='Available' THEN
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD('CheckoutDate:',30) 
                ||'****************************');
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD('DueDate:',30) 
               ||'****************************');
          ELSE
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD('CheckoutDate:',30) 
               ||RPAD(TO_CHAR(v_CheckoutDate, 'DD-MON-YYYY'),15));
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RPAD('DueDate:',30) ||RPAD(TO_CHAR( 
              v_DueDate, 'DD-MON-YYYY'),15));
        END IF;   END LOOP;  CLOSE asdf;   END IF; END proc_video_search ;
```

EXEC proc_video_search('ANOTHER', 'DVD')`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZAMd.png)

Comment: The result should be  1 result found for ANOTHER (Dvd). (Available copies: 1)                                                               
MY OUTPUT  "8 results found for ANOTHER(DVD) . (Available copies:6)"

Comment: Your cursor asdf has `OR t_video.format_name = p_formatName`. That means it would catch other DVDs that don't match the film name parameter. That may be why you are getting more results than you expected.

Comment: I must run two tests with FormatName and without.1.EXEC proc_video_search('ANOTHER', 'DVD') - When I use WHERE clause AND AND - its work for this test1 but not tets2.                                         2. EXEC proc_video_search('ANOTHER') - I used WHERE clause with AND OR its work correct for test 2

Comment: I would say first make sure your main cursor `asdf` retrieves the correct information first, before worrying about displaying it correctly. Run the `SELECT` statement in regular SQL, substituting the video name and format with predefined values. ("Another" and "DVD"). Once you get the expected output, then you can worry about wrapping it in a PL/SQL procedure.

Comment: Is this homework? This looks like homework.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line of your cursor `asdf`

```
 OR UPPER(T_VIDEO_FORMAT.NAME)= UPPER(p_FormatName)
```

Because it says `OR`, the query can choose to ignore this criteria if it evaluates to false. That is why you are getting results with all the formats; it ignores the filtering.

You have to wrap the `OR` statement in another `AND` clause, like so

```
WHERE Status !='D' 
AND UPPER(T_VIDEO.Name) like '%' || UPPER(p_VideoName) ||  '%'
AND ( /* OR clause here */ )
```

And then you can handle the case of **p_formatName being null or not**.